# Redirect with subdirections in node.js (express)

Tags: node.js

```
app.get('/rsg', (req, res) => res.redirect('https://robinschapendonk.ml/'))
app.get('/rsgbot', (req, res) => res.redirect('https://rsgbot.ml/'))
```

if you go to `mysite/rsgbot/invite` it should redirect to `rsgbot.ml/invite` and `mysite/rsgbot/login`should redirect to `rsgbot.ml/login` etc.., how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
app.get('/rsgbot/:something/', (req, res) => res.redirect('https://rsgbot.ml/'+req.params.something))
```

Comment: Can you also make it that it does work if there is not something?